# 日本語に違和感: ボタンのラベル: [対象]の[アクション]

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

- 「[タグ wiki の提案](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/delete-me/info)」
- 「編集内容の保存」: 投稿の編集フォーム

↓

- タグ wiki を提案
- 編集内容を保存

の方が、押すと何かが実行されるボタンのラベルとしてはより自然に聞こえます。

Answer (score 2):

> タグ wiki の提案

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40288221

> 編集内容の保存

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284669

がそれらしいですが、他の場面でも使いそうなフレーズなので確信が持てないです。

---

その他類似のケース。

- [○○の編集](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284595?qt=%E3%81%AE%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86)
- [○○の保存](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284669?qt=%E3%81%AE%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98)
- [○○の削除](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40288821)
- [クローズの提案](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286085)
- [資格情報の破棄](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40288590) ？？

Transifexで正規表現検索とかできたらいいんですが・・・。

Comment: ここだけに使っていると思いますので、とりあえず編集を進んでください。基本的には、ストリングを合体しないように頑張っていますので、「○○の編集」等を複数箇所に使われていないはずです。もしその編集をした後、バグが起こると、すぐに解決します。